# Updating data in FragmentStatePagerAdapter not working, getItem not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 5 fragments in a viewpager inside a fragment using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the 5 fragments has a date and a year parsed into them and they need to get data for that specific date. When i want to refresh the 5 fragments(and slide tabs) i re attach the fragment(the one with the viewpager) and update the dates parsed into the fragments, the name of the tabs update just right but the fragments dont, it seems like the FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem() is never called at all.

**First i update the "week" and call a method which re attaches the fragment**

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Forrige_uge:



            week = week -1;

            editor.putInt("uge",week);
            editor.putInt("år",year);
            editor.commit();



            lActivity.refreshSkemaFragment();
            return true;
        case R.id.Næste_uge:



            week = week +1;

            editor.putInt("uge",week);
            editor.putInt("år",year);
            editor.commit();



            lActivity.refreshSkemaFragment();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }'
```

**RefreshskemaFragment method**

```
protected void refreshSkemaFragment(){
    Fragment frg = null;
    frg =    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SKEMA_FRAGMENT_TAG");
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
}
```

**Then a if statement in onCreateView checks if this week already has data**

```
if (skemaDao.idExists("Uge " + week + " - " + year)) {
        //Do nothing if the table already exists, and just load the data from database

        isSynced = true;

        Log.v("idExists", "no sync");
    } else {
        //On first load start the

        isSynced = false;

        Log.v("idExists", "no data detected, start asynctask");

        new downloadLectio().execute();


    }
```

**if not a asynctask will be started and new data will be fethed and put into the database, all this works correctly then attachTabs() is called from the asynctask the update the viewpager with the correct data, if the data already exist it will just continue to the oncreateview and fill the viewpager with already existing data**

**attachTabs()**

```
public void attachTabs(){
    View rootView = getActivity().getWindow().findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost).getRootView();

    tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    // init view pager
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }
    });

    // insert all tabs from pagerAdapter data
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTab()
                        .setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this)
        );

}
```

**From here the ViewPagerAdapter is called**

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        Log.v("SkemaFragment current", "" + pos);

        Log.v("dato passed to indhold",datoer.get(pos));


        return SkemaFragmentIndhold.newInstance("" + year, datoer.get(pos));
    }






    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.v("getPageTitle", dage[position] + datoer.get(position));
        String tabTitle;

            tabTitle = dage[position] + "\n" + datoer.get(position);


        return tabTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }


}
```

The problem with this is i can never see the getItem get called in my log, it just seems like the fragments are "recreated" with the same parsed data as before, a hack i can think of is to just update the dates in sharedPrefences and not parse them from getItem, but i think this way is preferable.

Please ask further questions if need and in advance so much thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a adapter every single time and hence it will not update the data.